# How to create pygame rects one by one in a for loop?

Tags: python, pygame

I'm trying to create rects one by one. Each time the previous rect is deleted. The problem is that only the last one is created. If I comment out the line `if index != 0`, such that all rects are created in once, the program works. But I need to create the rects one by one.

```py
def draw_path(self, path):
    for index, i in enumerate(path):
        self.create_rect(colors['dark_red'], colors['red'], i[0] * TILE_SIZE, i[1] * TILE_SIZE, TILE_SIZE,TILE_SIZE)
        if index != 0:
            self.create_rect(colors['black'], colors['dark_gray'], path[index-1][0] * TILE_SIZE, path[index-1][1] * TILE_SIZE, TILE_SIZE, TILE_SIZE)
        self.player.position = (i[0], i[1])
```

I've tried to use the built in pygame functions `delay`, `wait` and `timer`, but it doesn't seem to fix the problem. Could anyone explain me, preferably with an example, how I can fix it?

Comment: If you need to create the rectangles one by one, you need to let your game update after creating one rect and before the next. It probably makes more sense to track how many rectangles you've drawn, and only draw one rectangle every time your function is called.

Answer (score 0):

you need to call the function `pygame.screen.update()` after each rect object is created and deleted if you want it to be displayed

Comment: Thank you! It's works! But, how to make delay with the better way? I had use pygame.time.delay and pygame.time.wait but it's looks like a game freeze, like a programm stop and waiting till loop is finished, which is looking weird.

Comment: What kind of an effect are you trying to achieve? If you don't want it to look like it has frozen, you don't need a pause Do you?

Comment: I'm trying to achieve movement of this rect in path array through cell by cell. If I don't use delay its seems move directly to last point. If I use inbuilt function pygame.time.delay or pygame.time.wait it's looking like program is freeze, I'm even cant move window until loop not finished.

And if journey is far program literally freeze (not response) until loop is not finished.

Many thank!

Comment: Ask on another question and lay out exactly what you want to achieve